# Update SharePoint document using python/powershell

Tags: python, powershell, sharepoint

Our company uses excel doc which is available in sharepoint webservice to track current project status. Is there any way i can update sharepoint document   programatically using python or Powershell.

The document requres credential as well to access hence checkout and check in required before updating docs.

let me know if anybody have come across this scenario...

Comment: Are you able to execute the Powershell from one of the SharePoint web front end servers, or are you constrained to accessing it remotely? If you can run it on a server on which SharePoint is installed, you'll have access to the server-side object model through Powershell; otherwise you're limited to client-side technologies and web services.

Comment: @Thriggle : i will be accessing the sharepoint remotely via weblink to update doc. link looks like ie: esg.one.bes.com/sites/server/doc.xls.   I tried installing sharepoint server 2013 in my win8.1 box . but due package error it doesnt progress . i am trying to replicate steps mentioned in below link [link](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2014/08/21/guest-blog-by-jonas-nilsson-install-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-7-8-8-1.aspx)

Comment: @PrMod you can update incase this share point site provide any API.